# unable to view all the text in textview

Tags: android

In the table row i have 2 textviews. but when i am trying to display text and if the text length is long i am not able to see all the string. only partially is visible

```
  <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Add"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/restaurant_address"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Restaurant_add"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:singleLine="false" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
```

I am not getting what's the error.. can i know what is the mistake i am doing?

i have set singleline to false also and ellipsize to end. but still i am facing same problem.

Thanks:)

Comment: Remove android:maxLines="2"

Comment: @Chirag i tried it.. but i am still facing same problem and even i tried adding scrolview also.. but it's not solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can put your LinearLayout in ScrollView, and if the Text is too long, you can scroll down and you'll see the whole String . . .

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <ScrollView>  

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Add"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/restaurant_address"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Restaurant_add"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:singleLine="false" />
            </LinearLayout>
           </ScrollView>
        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is there because of what:
    android:maxLines="2"

Remove it and it will be ok!

Answer (score 0):

please Use Linearlayout in place of tablerow.

Answer (score 0):

you can opt for multiple solutions...

-either set your textview to multiline as below

```
yourtextview.setSingleLine(false);
```

-this one is not the optimal one but you can also reduce the textsize of your textview...

hope this helps...